# URLSession concurrency issue for async calls

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency, nsurlsession

I am trying to implement upload mechanism for my application. However, I have a concurrency issue I couldn't resolve. I sent my requests using async/await with following code. In my application UploadService is creating every time an event is fired from some part of my code. As an example I creation of my `UploadService` in a for loop. The problem is if I do not use `NSLock` backend service is called multiple times (5 in this case because of loop). But if I use `NSLock` it never reaches the `.success` or `.failure` part because of deadlock I think. Could someone help me how to achieve without firing upload service multiple times and reaching success part of my request.

```
final class UploadService {
    /// If I use NSLock in the commented lines it never reaches to switch result so can't do anything in success or error part.
    static let locker = NSLock()

    init() {
        Task {
            await uploadData()
        }
    }

    func uploadData() async {
    //    Self.locker.lock()

        let context = PersistentContainer.shared.newBackgroundContext()
        // It fetches data from core data to send it in my request
        guard let uploadedThing = Upload.coreDataFetch(in: context) else {
            return
        }

        let request = UploadService(configuration: networkConfiguration)
        let result = await request.uploadList(uploadedThing)

        switch result {
        case .success:
            print("success")
        case .failure(let error as NSError):
            print("error happened")
        }

    //    Self.locker.unlock()
    }
}

class UploadExtension {
    func createUploadService() {
        for i in 0...4 {
            let uploadService = UploadService()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. You have to find what is recreating the service if you only want it to run once.

Comment: Does it matter? In my case it can be called multiple times. I think the question and what I am trying to achieve are clear. I just tried to show similar case.

Comment: I suspect it is unrelated to your question at hand, but `let request = UploadService(configuration: …)` seems like it must be a typo. Why would an upload service instance method create another upload service instance (and this time, using a `configuration` parameter that doesn’t exist in the implementation you shared with us).

Comment: Also unrelated, but it would appear that `uploadList` is returning a `Result` type. That is a bit of an anti-pattern in Swift concurrency. Just define it as an `async` method that `throws`.

Comment: Yep you are right it was my mistake thanks! Also thank you for your great recommendation. Throwing an error makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Never use locks (or wait for semaphores or dispatch groups, etc.) to attempt to manage dependencies between Swift concurrency tasks. This is a concurrency system predicated upon the contract that threads can make forward progress. It cannot reason about the concurrency if you block threads with mechanisms outside of its purview.
2. Usually you would not create a new service for every upload. You would create one and reuse it.

   E.g., either:

   ```swift
   func createUploadService() async {
       let uploadService = UploadService()

       for i in 0...4 {
           await uploadService.uploadData(…)
       }
   }
   ```

   Or, more likely, if you might use this same `UploadService` later, do not make it a local variable at all. Give it some broader scope.

   ```swift
   let uploadService = UploadService()

   func createUploadService() async {    
       for i in 0...4 {
           await uploadService.uploadData(…)
       }
   }
   ```
3. The above only works in simple `for` loop, because we could simply `await` the result of the prior iteration.

   But what if you wanted the `UploadService` keep track of the prior upload request and you couldn’t just `await` it like above? You could keep track of the `Task` and have each task `await` the result of the previous one, e.g.,

   ```swift
   actor UploadService {
       var task: Task<Void, Never>?                // change to `Task<Void, Error>` if you change it to a throwing method

       func upload() {
           …

           task = Task { [previousTask = task] in  // capture copy of previous task (if any)
               _ = await previousTask?.result      // wait for it to finish before starting this one

               await uploadData()
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   FWIW, I made this service with some internal state an `actor` (to avoid races).

Answer (score -1):

Since creating `Task {}` is part of structured concurrency it inherits environment (e.g MainThread) from the scope where it was created,try using unstructured concurrency's `Task.detached` to prevent it from runnning on same scope ( maybe it was called on main thread ) -  with creating Task following way:

```
Task.detached(priority: .default) {
 await uploadData()
}
```

Comment: Nope, thanks but it didn't work. It printed `success` 5 times again :(

Comment: Detached tasks solve a very different problem than we’re seeing here.

Comment: @Rob, you are right, thank you for the insight.